# OutOfMemoryError in SonarQube 5.6.4

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I'm trying to analyze a (large, ~900k lines of code) C# project which has worked well in an earlier version of SonarQube (5.4) but now fails (see stacktrace below).

I've tried to allocate more memory to the ComputeEngine (in 5.4 this seems to have shared resources with the main application) but still get the same error:

```
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

(from: `$SONAR_HOME\conf\sonar.properties`)

**Any suggestions what I need to do?**

Stacktrace:

```
2016.12.28 12:13:18 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute duplication measures | time=338ms
2016.12.28 12:15:51 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVlFV-iVMj2WmfjY00WT
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.DuplicationDataMeasuresStep$DuplicationVisitor.createXmlDuplications(DuplicationDataMeasuresStep.java:104) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.DuplicationDataMeasuresStep$DuplicationVisitor.computeDuplications(DuplicationDataMeasuresStep.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.DuplicationDataMeasuresStep$DuplicationVisitor.visitFile(DuplicationDataMeasuresStep.java:79) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitNode(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:79) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:51) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:98) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:98) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitChildren(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:98) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visitImpl(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.visit(DepthTraversalTypeAwareCrawler.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.DuplicationDataMeasuresStep.execute(DuplicationDataMeasuresStep.java:66) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
2016.12.28 12:15:51 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | type=REPORT | id=AVlFV-iVMj2WmfjY00WT | time=244116ms
```

Comment: I think you should use a bigger value for Xmx that's the maximal amount of memory that sonar will be use to get things done

Comment: Okay, I will increase the value even more. The default seems to be 512m though. Seems odd that I need to more than double the default setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx3G -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in `$SONAR_HOME\conf\sonar.properties` did the trick.